# jquery select all <a> beside some special <a>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am sorry for the title, don't know how to describe it better.

I have following structure:

```
<div id="content">
  <ul id="linklist">
     <li><a>...</a></li>
     <li><a>...</a></li>
     <li><a>...</a></li>
     <li><a>...</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a>...</a>
  <div> //variable depth of divs
    <a>...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select all links () beside the third and fourth one in the #linklist.

I've tried some jQuery selectors but i can't find a working one.

```
$(":not(#linklist li:gt(2) a) a")
```

does show the third and fourth link too. I think because the li are still exist in the match of "not".

What is the correct selector for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in your `:gt` selector is a little off. The `:gt` should be on the `#linklist a` elements, and the index is zero-based so should be `1`. Try this:

```
$('a:not(#linklist a:gt(1))')
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hL7aqqgL/)

Comment: I've tried before with
$('a:not(#linklist li:gt(1) a)')
but that isn't the solution. May you explain me why please?

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach it differently.
Give your elements that you don't want to select a unique class name (i.e `.ignore`)

```
     <li><a>...</a></li>
     <li><a>...</a></li>
     <li><a class="ignore-me">...</a></li>
     <li><a class="ignore-me">...</a></li>
```

Then you could simply do:

```
a:not(.ignore-me)
```

This will be more maintainable (i.e if your link position changes) and also work both with jQuery and CSS equally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well yes that's the easy way, but it isn't an alternative. The mark-up should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.not()` method with the two indexes you want to remove from the selection:

```
$('#linklist').find('a').not(':eq(2)').not(':eq(3)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#linklist li').not('li:nth-child(3)').not('li:nth-child(4)');
```

or:

```
$('#linklist li').not('li:gt(1)');
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/eadp1jL5/1/

Comment: I tried, it does not work.

        $('#linklist').not('li:nth-child(3)').not('li:nth-child(4)').find('li')

still find all <li>. Nevertheless i need the other <a> in collection too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`$('#linklist li').not(":eq(3)").not(":eq(2)")`